# Problems with networkx.to_numpy_matrix (or permutating a numpy matrix)

Tags: python, numpy, permutation, networkx

I am having a problem with how `networkx.to_numpy_matrix` works.

**Preface:** (with a working example)
I am working on my own implementation to check for graph isomorphisms. With a whole bunch of work I get a representation of my two graphs like this.

```
cc1:  [[8], [4], [7], [1], [3], [5], [2], [0], [6]]
cc2:  [[8], [0], [7], [3], [1], [5], [2], [4], [6]]
```

which represent a unique coloring of every node in my graph. With this I directly get a permutation from graph 1 to graph 2 that is a bijection and so both graphs are isomorphic. The permutation in this case is this

```
perms = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

`(0 -> 4, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 0, 5 -> 5, 6 -> 6, 7 -> 7, 8 -> 8)`

Now I want to check if the permutation really is correct (because I could get a few different permutations that are contenders and so I have to try them all. In this given case I only get one permutation). So I take a look at my adjancency matrix with `nx.to_numpy_matrix(self.g1)` and get

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

now I apply my permutation to that matrix

```
nx.to_numpy_matrix(self.g1, perms)
```

and get

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

which is equal to

```
nx.to_numpy_matrix(self.g2)
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

so that worked. Both graphs should have been isomorphic and I get the same result. Yay!

**Problem:**
The problem is that it doesn't always work. My problems start with the next example that also should be isomorphic.

```
cc1:  [[6], [7], [4], [5], [0], [1], [2], [3]]
cc2:  [[5], [7], [4], [1], [0], [3], [2], [6]]
perms: [0, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1, 5, 7]
```

so far so good

```
nx.to_numpy_matrix(self.g1)
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

nx.to_numpy_matrix(self.g1, perms)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

nx.to_numpy_matrix(self.g2)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

which is not equal. Why is `nx.to_numpy_matrix(self.g1, perms)` not working as I expect it to? Am I using it wrong?
I know that `perms` is correct, I know that the matrices are correct and I know that both graphs are isomorphic. How do I get `g1` correctly permutated with `perms` to get to `g2`?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't specify the node order (perms) in nx.to_numpy_matrix() then the result is arbitrary in that the order of the nodes is however the method G.nodes() returns them.  So you may want to specify the order [0, 1, 2, ...] to make sure everything is ordered in the sequence you want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was quite simple. I had the permutation the wrong way around. Example 1 just didn't throw an error because the permutation was symmetric (only `1 -> 3` and `3 -> 1`). When I switched the permutation, I got what I wanted. So it all worked as it is supposed to.